# Asian basket option variance reduction control variates monte carlo

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, asian-option, basket

I have priced an Asian put option with three underlying correlated stocks. Now I want to try to reduce the variance using control variates. I have found great ideas when there is one underlying (thus having the geometric Asian opition as a control variate). Is there any clean and simple way for doing this when there are more than one underlying?